# Use Cout to create asterisk shapes (No Loops)

Tags: c++

So, I've looked at other solutions with a similar problem to mine, but they all use loops to display the characters. What's required of me is to create 3 shapes using asterisks in C++. That's not so much the issue for me as actually getting them to display in the debugging window, instead of receiving a build error. Below is a test code of simply attempting to output the asterisk symbol:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main{
    cout << "*" << endl
}
```

resulting in the following block of errors (file location redundancy omitted):

> 1>source.cpp(10): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from'std::basic_ostream>' to 'int'
>
> 1>  source.cpp(10): note: Reason: cannot convert from 'std::basic_ostream>' to 'int'
>
> 1>  source.cpp(10): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
>
> 1>source.cpp(11): fatal error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found

I can only use programming based on what we've already learned, so I need to do these with nothing more than some basic cout statements.

Comment: So you have a build error but have not bothered to give the code or the error. You haven't explained exactly what you are trying to do. Just what kind of answer are you expecting?

Comment: You should show your code. Then others may be able to point to corrections or enhancements that can be made.

Comment: I wasn't looking for error correction, I asked if it was an available approach, but I'll edit the post to include the code.

Comment: Consider editing your question to remove the stuff about loops and stuff, and just focus why your code provided has build errors. You seem to be half asking about loops, and half asking about your build error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`main()` is missing parentheses, and the statement is missing a semicolon.

```
int main() {
//      ^^
    cout << "*" << endl;
//                     ^
}
```

Comment: I totally forgot about the parentheses. I had originally attempted using the semicolon after the statement, but it was rejected with similar errors, likely because of the lacking parentheses.

Comment: The `main` function is also missing a return value.